# Terminology for class

Tags: design-patterns, terminology

I am integrating with a Financial Management System (FMS). I have a class that prepares a set of objects (each of these objects is called a TransactionEntity). These are then passed to the FMS.
I give particular importance to correct terminology. What should I name this class that prepares the transactions? I am thinking TransactionSomething. Example TransactionBuilder, TransactionFactory etc. But I don't think these names are correct.
For the record, I use .Net but I don't think the framework should have an impact on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the objects being prepared are (each) named TransactionEntity, then I think **TransactionEntityBuilder** is a good name.

Comment: Thanks - yep I'll go for the Builder Term. Adding Entity to the name makes sense as well.